# server convert RAID1 to LVM and RAID1 server

Tags: server

I currently have my ubuntu server setup as such:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003d22b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   195350527    97674240   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2   *   195350528  3907028991  1855839232   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cd8db

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   195350527    97674240   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2   *   195350528  3907028991  1855839232   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md1: 1900.2 GB, 1900244959232 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 463926992 cylinders, total 3711415936 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md0: 100.0 GB, 99951181824 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 24402144 cylinders, total 195217152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I would like to transition to a RAID and LVM type of server without losing everything I have done to this point.
Is there a way I can save /dev/md1 and then drop it onto my newly created logical drive?